# copyItemAtPath return NO but the error is nil during unit testing

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have a following code, which copies folder from the app bundle to the Documents folder.

```
- (void)moveTessdataToDocumentsDirectoryIfNecessary
{
// Useful paths
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Create specified folder in the Documents directory first
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.dataPath] == NO) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:self.dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSString *tessdataFolderName = @"tessdata";
NSString *tessdataPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class].resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:tessdataFolderName];
NSString *destinationPath = [self.dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:tessdataFolderName];
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath] == NO && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tessdataPath]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"found %@", tessdataPath);
    NSLog(@"coping in %@", destinationPath);
    BOOL res = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
    if (!res) {
        NSLog(@"The result of copyItemAtPath == NO");
    }
    if(error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR! %@", error.description);
    }
}
}
```

It works fine in a sumilator and in a device.

The issue happens when I start unit tests for this function.
The output while unit testing is:

```
found /Users/kmakankov/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D28F7234-8C28-4325-BE7D-4DF113DF427E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EBD5C654-897B-4066-885B-986553D3459F/TestsProject.app/tessdata
coping in /Users/kmakankov/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D28F7234-8C28-4325-BE7D-4DF113DF427E/data/Containers/Data/Application/50D673A6-3F3E-42A1-98A1-DEAF9A4B2FBE/Documents/tes/tessdata
The result of copyItemAtPath == NO
```

So as you can see the `copyItemAtPath` return NO, but there is no error message, so I cannot understand what is the reason of the issue.
Furthemore, If I change `copyItemAtPath` with `moveItemAtPath` the function correctly moves the folder from the source to the destination during unit testing, so both source and destination paths are correct.

Does anybody knows what's wrong with `copyItemAtPath`?

Some extra info. I use iOS SDK 8.1.

Comment: Based on output while unit testing you're trying to copy data from App1.app to App2/Documents folder. I believe copyItemAtPath returns NO simply due to security restrictions

Comment: Is there a way to fix these security restrictions?

Comment: I checked this and can conclude, that both folders belong to the same app. IDs are just different for app bundle and Data folder in the simulator.